# How to use the carousel component from Bootstrap 4 with React.js?

Tags: reactjs, carousel, twitter-bootstrap-4

Here is the following code that I was trying to get to work with the carousel => That's basically the example given on the site.

No Error, The active slider is shown but the sliding effect can't seem to work, I don't know how to make it work with React. Am I doing it wrong? Is it related to 'href'? Please Help me. It's driving me nuts...

```html
import React from 'react';

export default class Slider extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" className="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol className="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" className="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div className="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div className="carousel-item active">
                        <img className="d-block img-fluid" src="resources/img/cd-background-img.jpg" alt="First slide"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="carousel-item">
                        <img className="d-block img-fluid" src="resources/img/home-bg.jpg" alt="Second slide"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="carousel-item">
                        <img className="d-block img-fluid" src="resources/img/home-bg.jpg" alt="Third slide"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a className="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span className="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span className="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a className="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span className="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span className="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: facing same problem . sliding isnt working

Answer (score 2):

Try https://github.com/leandrowd/react-responsive-carousel. I am using it and works very well!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option, this is a full bootstrap components migrated to React
[react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/carousel/).
Also for a complete project integrated with Material Design is here 
[React - Material Design for Bootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react)